# Cannot use "react.lazy" in webpack

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack

I'm having a problem using react.lazy in my webpack 4 project ("webpack": "^4.16.1")

this is my code for this problem:

```
import React, { Suspense, lazy } from "react";
const AccountInfo = lazy(() => import("../../views/Account")) ;

...

<Suspense fallback={<div>Loading...</div>}>
   <Switch>
     <PrivateRoute path="/accountinfo" component={AccountInfo} >
   <Switch/>
</Suspense >
```

this is file .babelrc

```
{
  "plugins": [
    [
      "transform-class-properties",
      {
        "spec": true
      }
    ]
  ]
}
```

and the error message is:
[image]

can someone help me?
Have a nice day guys <3

Answer (score 0):

I think, you need to add the `@babel/plugin-syntax-dynamic-import` plugin (https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-plugin-syntax-dynamic-import) and modify your `.babelrc` file.
Then it should be able to do the dynamic imports.

```
{
    "presets": [
      "@babel/preset-react"
    ],
    "plugins": [
      "@babel/plugin-syntax-dynamic-import"
    ]
}
```

You are also using an old version of webpack (version 4). Can you upgrade to a current version of webpack (5) (https://www.npmjs.com/package/webpack)?

Comment: thank you so much, but "@babel/plugin-syntax-dynamic-import " not working for  me becuase my version webpack and i resolve this problem by this article:
https://medium.com/front-end-weekly/lazy-loading-with-react-and-webpack-2-8e9e586cf442